# Any risks in using " for (i = 0; elem = array[i]; i++) " for iterating over an array?

Tags: javascript

Since I've discovered this snippet, I'm very often using it for iterating over arrays :

```
for (i = 0; elem = array[i]; i++) doStuff(elem);
```

It is obviously very wrong if `array` can contain anything that evaluates to false (`''`, `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `false`). But if you're sure that this is not the case, does anybody see another risk of using this method ?

I am asking this, since it doesn't seem to be very commonly used, though it seems really great to me, so I started thinking that there was an obvious drawback I was missing.

Comment: Well, the obvious drawback is the one you mention. It's very rare that you can guarantee only truthy elements.

Comment: When it comes to JavaScript, one can never be too sure.

Comment: As song as it is in you own personal code, it doesn't matter, but if it ever has a chance to be used by someone else, then it is a chance for hard to find bugs. Even for your own code if you change something... Therefore I don't think you should use it. It will probably bite you.

Comment: It happens quite often that I know for sure there wont be falsy values. For example a private array in which I push only values verified to be non-false. Readability is not an issue in the particular case I am using it for right now. However, you're right, I should watch out when using it at work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You know the drawbacks, as long as you can live with them...

Another way without the drawbacks could be

```
for (var i = 0, l = array.length, elem; i < l; elem = array[i++])
```

but it might be more obscure.

Comment: I usually write `for (var idx=0, len=array.length; idx < len; ++idx) { elem = array[idx]; ....stuff..... }` For me it is wrong to do anything more than increment or decrement in the last field.

Answer (score 5):

I think there are at least two major drawbacks:

- The first you already mentioned: it doesn't work if the array contains a falsy value. You can't always be sure that none of the elements will be falsy, both now *and in the future* as new features are added.
- The second is that it's *non-standard* and *confusing*. It will make other developers that have to maintain your code scratch their heads trying to figure out why you did that instead of a normal loop. Or they might misread it as `elem == array[i]`.

Keep it simple, both for yourself and your colleagues.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var elem = array[i];
    doStuff(elem);
}
```